# Не работает сеть

Tags: ubuntu

Есть Ubuntu 22.04, на ней стала пропадать сеть после перезагрузки, если ввести `dhclient`, то локальную сеть она видит, но снаружи не зайти. На внешние адреса тоже не выходит.

[image: скриншот 1]

[image: скриншот 2]

[image: скриншот 3]